# how to add custom scroll bar for textbox and listbox in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Can some explain thoroughly or share your source code on how to change textbox / listbox scroll bar to custom scroll bar on c# winforms.

Cause textbox and listbox doesnt have a scroll attribute like on panel. Thanks! Cant find a source code here to study, all i get is locating the scroll position using the GetScrollInfo API. I want to learn how set values or adapt my scroll bar to the default listbox and textbox. Thanks!

Comment: make textbox multiline and set its bounds. When text fills up the visible area you should get an automatic scrollbar. Depending on the control check its properties for AutoScrollbar, etc.

Comment: i want to use my custom scroll bar as the scroll bar for the textbox.

Comment: Have a quick read of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225444/richtextbox-handling-with-custom-scrollbar-in-c-sharp). The OP explains how he has achieved creating and using a custom scrollbar.

Comment: Textbox doesnt have access with scrollbar properties where richtextbox has.